How can I prevent a div with a column span of 2 in a Tailwind CSS grid layout, from overlapping the adjacent column with a span of 1?
I have a div with a grid of 3 columns (grid-cols-3), and then two child divs: one with a column span of 2 (col-span-2), and the other with a column span of 1 (col-span-1). I want to fix the div with a column span of 2. The issue is that when I use position: fixed, it uses the window's width and height, covering the column with a span of 1
Here's the code I'm using, could you help me fix it?
div className="h-full">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 w-full h-full">
          <div className="   col-span-2 h-full w-full top-0 overflow-y-hidden">
            <div className="w-full h-full bg-black text-white">ghhh</div>
          </div>
          
            <div
              id="content-wraper"
              className="col-span-1 bg-white h-full w-full   "
            ></div></div>


You could consider having a reference element in the grid layout, that you then size the position: fixed element with. The className attributes in your code imply you are using React, so here is an implementation in React:


const { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [style, setStyle] = useState({});
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const observer = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => {
      setStyle({
        top: entry.contentRect.top,
        left: entry.contentRect.left,
        height: entry.contentRect.height,
        width: entry.contentRect.width,
      });
    });
    observer.observe(ref.current);
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="h-full">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-3 w-full h-full">
        <div className="col-span-2 h-full w-full" ref={ref} />
        <div className="overflow-y-hidden fixed" style={style}>
          <div className="w-full h-full bg-black text-white">ghhh</div>
        </div>

        <div
          id="content-wraper"
          className="col-span-1 bg-white h-full w-full"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="app" class="h-96"></div>

<div class="h-screen"></div>



Hook up the reference element:
const ref = useRef(null);
…
<div className="grid grid-cols-3 w-full h-full">
  <div className="col-span-2 h-full w-full" ref={ref} />

Observe the positioning and size of the reference element:
const [style, setStyle] = useState({});
      
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  const observer = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => {
    setStyle({
      top: entry.contentRect.top,
      left: entry.contentRect.left,
      height: entry.contentRect.height,
      width: entry.contentRect.width,
    });
  });
  observer.observe(ref.current);
  return () => observer.disconnect();
}, []);

Set position: fixed on the "real" element:
<div className="overflow-y-hidden fixed">
  <div className="w-full h-full bg-black text-white">ghhh</div>
</div>

Apply the position and size data to our real element:
<div className="overflow-y-hidden fixed" style={style}>

